# Div width/height 100% of the free space inside another div

Tags: html, css

```css
#external
{
  background-color: #585858;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#internal
{
  background-color: #111858;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="external">
  content 1
  <div id="internal"></div>
</div>
```

In this case, how can I set a remnant height of external div to the internal div?
The problem is when I set 100% height to internal div, so internal height == external height.

Comment: Add content  in content div(new div for content), that will solve the issue.

Comment: Consider visiting this question: [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is a little unclear but `flexbox` can do what I *think* you are after.

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.external {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
}
.internal {
  background-color: #111858;
  100%;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="external">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  <div class="internal"></div>
</div>
<div class="external">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo harum quia tempore! Sit, laboriosam, quam.</p>
  <div class="internal"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this may help u

```
<style>
    #external
    {
      background-color: #585858;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }
    #internal
    {
      background-color: #111858;
      width: 50px;
      height: calc(100% - 20px);
    }
    .content
    {
    height:20px;
    }
</style>

<div id="external">
  <div class="content">content 1</div>
  <div id="internal"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the external must be without fixed width/height.

Comment: what you are trying to do

Comment: divs container with unfixed size